# How do I unlock an Optimus T? Is there a "vanilla" firmware I can use?

Tags: sim-unlocking, vanilla-android

I'm an experienced iOS developer, and I just bought my first Android phone, used, on eBay. The phone is carrier locked and I'm looking to swap in my iPhone SIM card. (I have an adapter.)

The phone is carrier locked. Is there a way to root or erase the firmware to unlock it, or must I use an unlock code? If so, what are my options for obtaining said code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears your only option is an unlock code, I've just done a search.  [This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=853971) has a couple ways to get into the unlock screen so you can enter the code.

Your options for get the unlock code are to ask the carrier the phone is locked to -- they might give it to you if they're feeling nice -- or to buy it online.  There are no reputable sellers of unlock codes online, of course, but you could search around and find someone whose experience seems reliable and use the same service that they did.

Answer (score 1):

I have this phone, and I have T-Mobile.  I called *611 and told them I was going to be traveling in Europe and needed a SIM unlock code.  They agreed and it arrived about 12 hours later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unlock code to unlock your LG Optimus T which is the safe and easy way. You can get the unlock code from the service/network provider. But,Mostly they will provide the unlock code if your phone if off contract . In that case you can get the unlock code from online vendors like [MobileUnlockSolutions.com](http://www.mobileunlocksolutions.com/lg-optimus-t/rs16wp9/) for a price .They will give you the unlock code along with instruction on how to unlock.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for you. Get your LG Optimus unlocked by obtaining an unlock code so that you will be able to swap in your iPhone SIM card. Just google for cheap LG SIM/Network Unlock codes. Be careful about sites that betrays you. You can also find some code vendors on ebay too.